# Jump-To-Code-Line Eclipse Shortcuts

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, key, shortcut

is it possible, in Eclipse, to mark certain lines with Shortcuts and be able to quickly jump to those lines?

Example: Let's say I have maintenanceHeavyMethod() at line 120 in my class, gameLoop() at line 800 and some listener at line 1460.

I'd like to f.ex. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> etc. to mark those positions, and then use f.ex. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> to immediately jump to them. I don't like split-screens etc, but I need to jump around when writing.

Is there such a feature?

I'm using latest Eclipse to write Java-programs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add **Bookmarks** in your code. Select the code fragment you want to bookmark and then go to **Edit > Add Bookmark...** (also possible via the menu available with a **right-click** in the left hand column of the editor, like breakpoints).

Then, add the **Bookmarks view**. Select **Window > Show View > Other... > Bookmarks** and you'll get something like this:

[image]

Sadly, I don't think you can bind a shortcut to a particular bookmark.

Just in case, the shortcut to jump to a particular line is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Bookmark!... The obvious solution that somehow I didn't thought about when writing my own answer ;) +1

Comment: @VonC Bookmarks are not an hidden feature but they are not frequently used to my experience. Maybe because they are missing assignable shortcuts :)

Comment: Yes, that works very well. I guess I could've found that by clicking around more. Even though it's not shortcuts, it does what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That would be best taken care by **[mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)**:

Define a task with this three method, and you will be to see only those 3 in the package explorer view

[image: http://www.tasktop.com/sites/default/files/images/part1-overview.jpg]

Comment: WHat is your experience using Mylyn on a day to day basis?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: it requires discipline to manage your tasks, but if they are well-defined and tight enough, it is very effective.

Comment: @VonC, Your screen doesn't look like there's any space left allocated to code.....

Comment: @Pacerier sure, it was one of the screenshots illustrating mylyn features, so they (the features) are displayed here to the exclusion of anything else. But obviously you can reorganize those views in any way you want, and make room for the code.

Answer (score 2):

To jump to a particular method, I use ctrl+o and then start typing the method.  If you're a proficient typist, this shouldn't take any longer; keep in mind that you only have to start typing the name of the method.

Unfortunately this isn't a proper solution for jumping to a line of code within a method.

Comment: If you dont know the exact name, but only a part of the name, start by `*name*`, where `*` represents any thing before and after name.

Comment: Ctrl Shift T is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to methods by using the outline view. Outline view shows all the Methods, Fields, and Inner-Classes (and their methods and fields and inner-classes...etc) of the source file you currently have open. I personally prefer this method, unless I have a stacktrace and know which line I want to jump to, in which case I use ctrl+L.